# ASP Classic session string is canceling concatenation

Tags: string, vbscript, asp-classic

I have come across a puzzler regarding string behavior in ASP classic.

The code pulls in some values from session and then attempts to use those as strings.

The problem is that the value is somehow canceling string concatenation.

```
Dim testVar
testVar = session("test") <- this value is "aaa"
response.write "XXX - " & testVar & " - XXX"
```

That code prints `XXX - aaa`

Alternatively, if I set testVar to some string value a la `testVar="bbb"`, the string concatenation works as expected.

One more thing I discovered in trying to figure this out...

`StrComp(testVar, "aaa" ,0)`  returns 1
`StrComp(testVar, "aaa" ,1)`  returns 0

So any ideas why my testVar is killing the concatenation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `StrComp` behaviour is what you would see if there were a null character on the end of the string; this would also prevent the subsequent concatenation.

You can verify this by seeing if `ascw(right(testVar, 1)) = 0`

Chop it off: `testVar = left(testVar, len(testVar) - 1)`

Comment: Ok, that did the trick, but now I have to wonder why this null character is being added?

This came up because we moved an old application from a Win 2003 Server to Win 2008.

Comment: Wherever `session("test")` is assigned to presumably - this can happen with some COM calls

Comment: No code changes were made, so it's odd that the server change did this, no?

Comment: I don't supposed you have any idea on how I could track something like this down?  If I can't find a global setting for this, it's going to require a lot of code change.

Comment: Track how/what is the session variable is assigned, the issue will be there

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from

```
>> For Each s In Array("AB", "A" & Chrw(0))
>>     s = "XXX - " & s & " - XXX"
>>     WScript.Echo Len(s), s
>> Next
>>
14 XXX - AB - XXX
14 XXX - A
```

ChrW(0)s neither cancel nor prevent **concatenation**. The **display** problem is caused by pecularities of VBScript's IO methods.

If you have one place/piece of code for either getting or displaying testVar (which you probably should), one

```
s = Replace(s, ChrW(0), "WhateverMakesSenseInYourContext")
```

should do the trick.

Evidence:

```
>> For Each s In Array("AB", "A" & Chrw(0))
>>     s = "XXX - " & s & " - XXX"
>>     s = Replace(s, ChrW(0), "")
>>     WScript.Echo Len(s), s
>> Next
>>
14 XXX - AB - XXX
13 XXX - A - XXX
```

Further food for thought:

```
Option Explicit

Const csFSpec = ".\29988189.data"

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim sData : sData    = "Danger" & ChrW(0) & " Will Robinson!"
Dim tsIO  : Set tsIO = goFS.CreateTextFile(csFSpec)
tsIO.WriteLine sData
tsIO.Close
sData = goFS.OpenTextFile(csFSpec).ReadLine()
WScript.Echo Len(sData), Replace(sData, ChrW(0), ",")
```

Output:

```
cscript 29988189.vbs
22 Danger, Will Robinson!
```